# find command no such file or directory error

Tags: linux, find

I am using this command to delete the files and folders older than 150 days

```
 find /media/Server/VPS/dailySQL/* -mtime +140 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

The problem is that i get the error like below

```
find: `/media/May-08-Sat-2010': No such file or directory
find: `/media/May-11-Tue-2010': No such file or directory
find: `/media/May-12-Wed-2010': No such file or directory
find: `/media/May-13-Thu-2010': No such file or directory
find: `/media/May-14-Fri-2010': No such file or directory
```

why is that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ find /media/Server/VPS/dailySQL/ -mtime +140 | xargs rm -rf
```

Answer (score 8):

Because you're removing the directories, and then trying to descend into them. Add `-prune` to the end.

Comment: This shall be the corret answer.

Answer (score 3):

Problem with a couple of the proposed suggestions is that if any of the files/directories have special characters, they will not be deleted.  Doing an -exec in the submitters lins is really time consumming and better efficiency is done by piping the names to xargs and invoking the rm/rmdir in as few times as possible.

```
 touch /media/Server/VPS/dailySQL/.saver     
 find /media/Server/VPS/dailySQL -type f -mtime +140 -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f >/dev/null 2>&1
 find /media/Server/VPS/dailySQL -depth -type d -print0 | xargs -0 rmdir >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The second line deletes all the old files.  I put a file in the top level directory to save it from destruction on the first line and finally you run through the directories depth-first and simply try to rmdir.  If there is something still present, the rmdir will fail.  Depth-first is necessary to remove empty sub-directories before a given directory is attempted to be removed.

Finally, notice -print0 and the -0 parameter on xargs.  This allows you to process files that have spaces or other meta characters in them properly.  This feature is available on most Linux systems I have been exposed to lately.

This is the type of scripting I used to remove /tmp and /var/tmp items.

Enjoy